# Slide it automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far this code will only slide the image by clicking the thumnail on it. When we click the thumnail image, the slideshow will slide the image. But now I ALSO want it to slide the image automatically in every 10 second.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/rj3yuvvy/5):

The Html

```
    <ul id="slide-wrapper">
        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/120/120"/>         
        <p class="caption-title">Linkin Park's 'The Hunting Party': Track-by-Track Review</p></li>


        <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/120/120"/>         
        <p class="caption-title">Sarah Jaffe Video Premiere Watch The Haunting Lover Girl Clip</p></li>             
    </ul>

    <ul class="thumnails">
        <li class="img-thum">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/120/120"/>
            <p class="thum-capt">Linkin Park's 'The Hunting Party': Track-by-Track Review</p></li>


        <li class="img-thum">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/120/120"/>
            <p class="thum-capt">Bottled Water Comes From the Most Drought-Ridden Places in the Country</p></li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

---

The JS

```
//When we click on thumb img
$('.thumnails li').click(function() {

var
   //SlideShow
   sshow = $(this).closest('#slideshow'),
   //Big
   big = sshow.find('#slide-wrapper'),
   //thumb
   thumb = sshow.find('.thumnails'),
   //Get index
   indx = thumb.find('li').index(this),
   //Current index
   currentIndx = big.find('li').index(big.find('li:visible'));

   //If currentIndx is same as clicked indx don't do anything
   if(currentIndx == indx) {
      return;
   }

 big
    //Fadeout current image
    .find('li:visible').fadeOut(0).end()
    //Fadein new image
    .find('li:eq(' + indx + ')').fadeIn(0);
 });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger a click on your "slide button" every 10 seconds in document.ready using setInterval function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){ 
        //Your code inside here will be executed every 10 seconds
        $('.thumnails li').trigger("click");
    }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: I just don't know where to put the code: I put your code bellow my code, but it doesn't work. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/rj3yuvvy/6/

Comment: You put it correctly but it seems I got it wrong on how the system works because it seems you have a different button, however note that I updated my thread and .delay(1000). was a misstake of mine and should be removed.

Comment: still doens't work. Can you please create me the fiddle for that?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

```
setTimeout(function (){
 autoSlide();
},10000);
```

Next, put the slide code in a function like autoSlide and than wil he run the code automaticly every 10 seconds.

Put that function also in you click event.

Comment: Can you combine it with my code above, and create the fiddle, please? I just don't know where to put it.